# Can't connect to postfix from client

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I'm attempting to set up a Postfix, Dovecot, Spamassassin email stack and have everything installed and configured.

However, every time I try to connect to my server with my client, it fails to connect to the outgoing server (no issues configuring the incoming). I've tried with both Thunderbird (on my PC) and Bluemail (on my phone).

The `mail.log` shows the two lines when I try to connect to the outgoing server:

```
Aug 11 12:39:07 pyrosoftsolutions postfix/smtpd[13039]: lost connection after EHLO from 60.216.208.46.dyn.plus.net[46.208.216.60]
Aug 11 12:39:07 pyrosoftsolutions postfix/smtpd[13039]: disconnect from 60.216.208.46.dyn.plus.net[46.208.216.60] ehlo=1 commands=1
```

I've tried connecting on port 587 with and without authentication.

My netstat shows that postfix is in fact listening on the right port:

```
root@pyrosoftsolutions:/home/james# netstat -ntlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1489/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3128            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1090/(squid-1)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2190/flarecoind
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39002         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2190/flarecoind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1876/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1545/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1505/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1862/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1350/systemd-resolv
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1876/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1489/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      2192/gitea
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1876/nginx: master
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      1545/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      1862/master
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN      1350/systemd-resolv
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1876/nginx: master
```

Here's my `master.cf` file:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

And my `ufw status verbose`:

```
root@pyrosoftsolutions:/home/james# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
39001                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
39002                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3128                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp (Postfix)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
3000                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
587                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2048,3128,3130,3401,4827/tcp (Squid) ALLOW IN    Anywhere
993                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
995                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
465                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
39001 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
39002 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3128 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (Postfix (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
587 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
2048,3128,3130,3401,4827/tcp (Squid (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
993 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
995 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
465 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Weirdly enough, however, I can `telnet` port 587 internally and externally with no issue.

Any advice?

Comment: There's no problem description. Please add it, otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: Second paragraph? I've expanded on it though

Comment: "It fails" is no problem description

Comment: "failed to connect" is the only error message I get

Comment: Log output from the servers?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've been ill. What log files am I looking for? I can't find any for postfix

Comment: If you are not able to find logs of your own server, you should probably not administrate it. They are usually in `/var/log/mail.log`.

Comment: I was being stupid... I was looking for a `/var/log/mail/` directory, please see my question for updated info

Comment: Well, the client connects and then disconnects...

Comment: As far as the logs are concerned, yes, but both clients say that they can't connect

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. There is nothing in /var/log/mail.log showing any attempt by a client to connect

Comment: Persistence: did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I gave up on self hosting

Comment: Sebix: In my case, there is no output from the servers because there is no connection. I've tried two different clients and it just times out for both of them. Thunderbird on my desktop and Blue Mail on my phone.

Comment: Several years ago I had this set up and working on Rackspace. Now I am on DigitalOcean.